# How to 'Git Remove' files from a deleted folder?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using git remove `git rm`. I made the simple/stupid mistake of **manually** deleting a folder with all the files in it **BEFORE** I used `git rm`.

Now I have >15 files that I want to delete from my repo but NOT type out.

Is there a way to do this?

```
git status

deleted:    Literature/abc.md
deleted:    Literature/acdf.pdf
deleted:    Literature/dsfsdf.pdf
deleted:    Literature/dfgdfs.pdf
deleted:    Literature/sgadfgaa.md
deleted:    Literature/sdsds.pdf
deleted:    Literature/sddvasds.rmd
deleted:    Literature/ddsds.md
deleted:    Literature/fsdfsdsd.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they're deleted from your *worktree*, but these files were saved in last revision*, so you just have to restore these files as they were at last commit :

```
git checkout -- full/path/to/Literature/
```

then `rm` them as you intended in the first place.

* *(unless these are new added files but you didn't say so)*

Comment: i did a `git checkout {number}` but now I have a detached head.

Comment: @oaxacamatt That's not a problem, just checkout your branch again with `git checkout <yourBranch>`. But I don't get why you typed that. Was it on purpose? The `--` in my code is not a placeholder for numbers, just a way to tell git "anything after that is not parameters but file pathes" Can you share what you typed exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have **no other changes** currently, and **you are sure** you need to revert back to the last committed state,

you can use , `git reset --hard` which moves the HEAD to last committed hash and **discarding all your local changes after that commit**

Or, safer way is to do a `git reset {path to your deleted folder}` first, to make the files unstaged for next commit, and then doing `git checkout -- {path to your deleted folder}` as suggested by @RomainValeri

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
git rm -r --cached
```

For more details follow the link [Bit Bucket Documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-rm)